# New Google maps on iOS 6 implementation crash

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, ios6

I successfully  implement new SDK from Google to my test project on iOS 6. When I add code from there tutorial I get such exception:

```
GoogleMapsBack[7306:5103] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'GMSCachedTile''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x27b0012 0x25d5e7e 0x10373e7 0x34bea 0x30c52 0x2a4f53f 0x2a61014 0x2a51418 0x2a512a6 0x2a52280 0x2a52450 0x97401e12 0x973e9cca)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Does anyone know what is it the problem ?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

Comment: how did you register for API key? did google contact you when key became available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot step 4:
"Drag the GoogleMaps.bundle from the Resources folder to your project. We suggest putting it in the Frameworks group. When prompted, ensure Copy items into destination group’s folder is not selected."
i encountered the same problem, and this fixed it.
regards, 
Tomer

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it's look like that, but now I have a problem with ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)
I know that it should be like :  If you see the marker, but the map is not visible, confirm that you have provided your API key.

Comment: I have found the same issue about the DASHConnectionError Code=100 messages. After tirelessly searched on the internet, it seems like Google has not provide the iOS Oauthen Token for iOS developer yet. They just provide how to use the token but it is never exists.

Comment: but, i didn't see any service named for iOS while creating the project! any solution?

Comment: With new SDK Google implement the demo project but when I put there a api key it dose not work again. + I have invitation from Google but it dose not help me in solving of maps problem.